# PHP memcache::addServer, weight

Tags: php, memcached

My question is related to the "weight" parameter in the addServer function of the PHP Memcache extension. 
For last couple of months, I have been using "weight = 1" for all servers. I am now trying to apply the configurations below to eventually remove "10.10.10.3" from the rotation and minimize data loss. 
With the new weight values in place, my PHP client fails to retrieve value for keys that it used to be able to fetch. If I revert to "weight = 1", all keys can be fetched without any problem. 
Is there a configuration or anything I am missing in order to use the "weight" option correctly with "Memcache::addServer"?

Thank you for your help.

```
 $hosts = array(
      array('ip' => '10.10.10.1', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 100),
      array('ip' => '10.10.10.2', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 100),
      array('ip' => '10.10.10.3', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 1),
      array('ip' => '10.10.10.4', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 100),
 );

 $memcache = new Memcache();
 foreach($hosts as $host) {
    $host['port'] = isset($host['port']) ? (int) $host['port'] : 11211;
    $host['weight'] = isset($host['weight']) ? (int) $host['weight'] : 1;
    $memcache->addserver($host['ip'], $host['port'], false, $host['weight'], 1, 15);
 }
```

---

**PHP version** = 5.3.10

**Memcache PHP variables**
 - memcache support => enabled
 - memcache.allow_failover => 1 => 1
 - memcache.chunk_size => 32768 => 32768
 - memcache.compress_threshold => 20000 => 20000
 - memcache.default_port => 11211 => 11211
 - memcache.hash_function => crc32 => crc32
 - memcache.hash_strategy => consistent => consistent
 - memcache.lock_timeout => 15 => 15
 - memcache.max_failover_attempts => 20 => 20
 - memcache.protocol => ascii => ascii
 - memcache.redundancy => 1 => 1
 - memcache.session_redundancy => 2 => 2

**Memcached versions**
10.10.10.1 / 10.10.10.2 / 10.10.10.3 are running 1.4.5 
10.10.10.4 is running 1.4.4

Comment: Everything I've read says to use PHP's Memcached extension instead of PHP's Memcache extension.  Sorry I can't cite anything now (I didn't bookmark any of it), I just know because I chose to use the former in production.  =)  This might be one of the caveats that caused me to choose the Memcached extension over the Memcache extension.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The weight parameter effects the consistent hashing used to determine which server to read/write keys from.  Changing the weight of any 1 server in the pool will result in some cache misses.  The number of servers in the pool and how much you change the weight will factor in on how many misses you may experience.

What you need to understand is that memcached is distributed which means that since you have 4 servers, keys are distributed amongst each of those servers (as close to evenly as possible [weight will effect even distribution]).  If one server goes down, the data stored on that server is no longer accessible and will have to be fetched from the database as it is not available on any other servers.  *Note that the PHP extensions `memcache` and `memcached` are just clients that access a `memcached` cluster (memcached was the newer of the two and supported more features, but both talk to servers in a memcached cluster).

When you want to store or retrieve a value from the cache, a hash is computed which determines where in the cluster the data should be put or read from.  A common way to illustrate this is with a 360 degree circle as seen below.  You calculate a hash, and use the node that it lands "closest" to in the circle.  Adding or removing servers, or changing the weight of any one server will effect the outcome of the hashing and result in a miss.

[image]
Source: http://alpha.mixi.co.jp/blog/?p=158

If you want to phase a server out of the cluster slowly, I would recommend gradually decreasing its weight until it is 0 and you can then remove the server from the list completely.  Keep in mind, any small change in weight can/will result in cache misses, but how much the weight changes (and how many servers you have) influences how many misses you will experience.

Here is a snippet from the [Memcached tutorial story](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/TutorialCachingStory) that may help explain some of this as well.

The preface is that two sysadmins set up a memcached cluster with 3 servers, and told memcached to use 1GB on each server...

> So again, he takes keys that the Programmer uses and looks for them on
>   his memcached servers. 'get this_key' 'get that_key' But each time he
>   does this, he only finds each key on one memcached! Now WHY would you
>   do this, he thinks? And he puzzles all night. That's silly! Don't you
>   want the keys to be on all memcacheds?
>
> "But wait", he thinks "I gave each memcached 1 gigabyte of memory, and
>   that means, in total, I can cache three gigabytes of my database,
>   instead of just ONE! Oh man, this is great," he thinks. "This'll save
>   me a ton of cash. Brad Fitzpatrick, I love your ass!"
>
> "But hmm, the next problem, and this one's a puzzler, this webserver
>   right here, this one runing memcached it's old, it's sick and needs to
>   be upgraded. But in order to do that I have to take it offline! What
>   will happen to my poor memcache cluster? Eh, let's find out," he says,
>   and he shuts down the box. Now he looks at his graphs. "Oh noes, the
>   DB load, it's gone up in stride! The load isn't one, it's now two.
>   Hmm, but still tolerable. All of the other memcacheds are still
>   getting traffic. This ain't so bad. Just a few cache misses, and I'm
>   almost done with my work. So he turns the machine back on, and puts
>   memcached back to work. After a few minutes, the DB load drops again
>   back down to 1, where it should always be.
>
> "The cache restored itself! I get it now. If it's not available it
>   just means a few of my requests get missed. But it's not enough to
>   kill me. That's pretty sweet."

The moral is that values stored in memcached are only stored on one server (that is the keys are distributed amongst all servers) and if any one of those servers becomes unavailable, the data is not available from cache and has to be fetched from the source.

In order to properly store and retrieve data from the correct nodes in the cluster, keys must be [consistently hashed](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommonFeatures#Consistent_Hashing) so the client knows which server is the correct one in the pool for that particular key.

As you may guess, different clients use different hashing techniques so using a Perl client and a PHP client to store/retrieve values will not work as intended since they hash differently.  The exception to this is any client that uses [libmemcached](http://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html) since then they will all be using the same hashing algorithm.  PHP's [memcached](http://php.net/memcached) extension uses `libmemcached`, where the [memcache](http://php.net/memcache) does not and uses its own hashing algorithm (as far as I know).

Further Reading:
 - [memcached wiki](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewStart?tm=6) and the [adventure in learning memcached](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/TutorialCachingStory)
 - [Consistent Hashing](http://www.tomkleinpeter.com/2008/03/17/programmers-toolbox-part-3-consistent-hashing/)
 - [Distributed Hash Tables](http://offthelip.org/?p=149)

Comment: IMO, this response further confuses the issue. The API call is made to the PHP `memcache` wrapper, which is based off of `memcached`. However if he used the PHP `memcached` wrapper, which is based off of `libmemcached`, he would then get the benefits of a truly distributed key/value caching solution. As stated via the libmemcached website, some of the features: "Local replication" along with "consistent hashing and distribution". http://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html

Comment: I think that both PHP `memcache` and `memcached` use consistent hashing algorithms, they are just different ones so they aren't inter-operable.  Since the C library `libmemcached` is very common, it is easy to find and use libraries in different languages (e.g. PHP and Ruby) that both use the same consistent hashing algorithm and therefore will hash keys the same from both languages.  But whether or not one uses PHP `memcache` or `memcached`, keys are still distributed and only live on 1 server in the cluster as opposed to living on every server in the cluster.

Comment: Perhaps I am losing something in translation. So you are saying that if I used the `memcached` api wrapper (based off of libmemcached), and server3 goes down (5 total), any calls to these missing keys will result in trips to the persistent store, as they will not be re-distributed to the other, active servers?

Comment: Correct, when they say it is distributed, they mean that keys are distributed across all the available servers rather than stored on every one.  This is part of the beauty behind memcached in that if you have 10 servers each with 1GB of cache, you end up with 10GB of cache space rather than 1GB.  This can have its own consequences as they illustrate in the memcached story.  But that is correct, keys DO NOT go on every server, only 1 in the cluster.

Comment: Here is some good reading on this:  http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewConfiguringClient#Failure,_or_Failover and also from [here](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/TutorialCachingStory)`Ctrl-F` `Programmer pushes code. Sysadmin sweats` and read from there

Comment: Ya, I understand the idea behind the collective memory sharing between multiple cache servers, just thought that the keys would be replicated under the hood to ensure no data loss if a server goes down. Btw, those memcached wiki entries are terrible, they sould just succinctly state how it works under the hood.

Comment: Yah I agree there is a lot to be desired on those pages :)  I think some of the answers on [NewProgrammingFAQ](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingFAQ) are helpful, and the [Servers are Disconnected From Eachother](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewOverview#Servers_are_Disconnected_From_Each_Other) section on NewOverview clarify some of this stuff.

Comment: Just found this page [about memcached](http://memcached.org/about) which is somewhat informative, at least it vaguely states "...that a given item is always stored and always retrieved from the same location in your entire web cluster" and also "If you had fifty web servers, you'd still have a usable cache size of 64MB in the first example, but in the second, you'd have 3.2GB of usable cache" which is not very helpful without the image context.

Comment: Thanks for clarification for under-the-hood activity. Updated my answer to reflect changes.

Comment: No problem, it helps me understand it more as well digging in.  For the longest time I was really confused on how it all worked (thanks to the vague docs).

Comment: Another decent article: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/theTechTrek/entry/getting_started_with_memcached_libmemcached2?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The problem is that you are using [memcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcache.php) vs [memcached](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcached.php). Memcached is distributed, meaning that all servers added to the pool act as one cache server. So if server1 is down, you can still retrieve keys/values because they are distributed across the other three servers. Whereas with memcache (no d),</strike> each server is basically a silo, meaning that key/values stored on server1 are not guaranteed to be present on any of the other cache servers.

If you want to deprecate the cache server in question, I'd suggest adding some extra logic to your api call to pull the value from the persistent store, then store it across at least two of the other valid cache servers. I've seen projects where a cache value will be saved across two cache servers to ensure that one server is not longer responding, the other server can pick up the slack.

**-- Update --**

Regardless which PHP memcache API is used, if a server is removed from the pool, it will result in cache misses for keys residing on now missing server. When the `$cache->get()` fails and goes to the persistent store, and `$cache->set()` is called, the cache will now be stored on a different, active server. Thanks to Drew010 for clarification on this.

You can still write your app to write the same cache value to multiple servers if you absolutely cannot afford any cache misses.

Comment: Thank you for response. Even though I understand the difference between memcached vs memcache, I still don't understand how modifying the weight could have such impact. Should memcache still be calling server 10.10.10.3 even though it has a weight of 1?

Comment: According to php docs about the `$weight` argument: "Number of buckets to create for this server which in turn control its probability of it being selected. The probability is relative to the total weight of all servers." Which leads me to believe that, although it is improbable that the server will be selected, it is not impossible. I would suggest removing the server from the servers array to ensure it is impossible to be selected.

Comment: In fact, I just did some testing and as soon as weight <> 1 for all servers, some values will be missing. That's really where I am confused.

Comment: As I mentioned in my solution, the values are not distributed. Are you certain that the values are stored on EVERY server in your array? If not, then if a server gets selected that doesn't contain the expected value, it will return nothing.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part - makes sense now, thanks for your help.